# AssertionError: False is not true when moving to Function Based Views

Tags: python, django, django-models, tdd, django-views

I am using Test Driven Development methods to create a basic blog in Django 1.6.

I followed [this tutorial](http://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2013/12/28/django-blog-tutorial-the-next-generation-part-1/) but wanted to change to using Function Based Views since I'm just starting with Django.

I get this error in my tests and no content shows on my index.html template:

```
self.assertTrue(post.title in response.content)
AssertionError: False is not true
```

I commented it out to see if it was just that line, but it happens to all of my `self.assertTrue` tests in `def test_index(self):` which is in `class PostViewTest(LiveServerTestCase):`

## # my_site > ingeldow > templates > blogengine > index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Django Blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for post in object_list %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <h3>{{ post.pub_date }}</h3>
        {{ post.text }}
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

## # my_site > ingeldow > blogengine > tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase, LiveServerTestCase, Client
from django.utils import timezone
from blogengine.models import Post

# Create your tests here.
class PostTest(TestCase):
    def test_create_post(self):
        # Create the post
        post = Post()

        # Set the attributes
        post.title = 'My first post'
        post.text = 'This is my first blog post'
        post.pub_date = timezone.now()

        # Save it
        post.save()

        # Check we can find it
        all_posts = Post.objects.all()
        self.assertEquals(len(all_posts), 1)
        only_post = all_posts[0]
        self.assertEquals(only_post, post)

        # Check attributes
        self.assertEquals(only_post.title, 'My first post')
        self.assertEquals(only_post.text, 'This is my first blog post')
        self.assertEquals(only_post.pub_date.day, post.pub_date.day)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.pub_date.month, post.pub_date.month)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.pub_date.year, post.pub_date.year)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.pub_date.hour, post.pub_date.hour)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.pub_date.minute, post.pub_date.minute)
        self.assertEquals(only_post.pub_date.second, post.pub_date.second)

class AdminTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    fixtures = ['users.json']

    def setUp(self):
        # Create client
        self.client = Client()

    def test_login(self):
        # Get login page
        response = self.client.get('/admin/')

        # Check response code
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

        # Check 'Log in' in response
        self.assertTrue('Log in' in response.content)

        # Log the user in
        self.client.login(username='test', password="password")

        # Check response code
        response = self.client.get('/admin/')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

        # Check 'Log out' in response
        self.assertTrue('Log out' in response.content)

    def test_logout(self):
        # Log in
        self.client.login(username='test', password="password")

        # Check the response code
        response = self.client.get('/admin/')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

        # Check 'Log out' in response
        self.assertTrue('Log out' in response.content)

        # Log out
        self.client.logout()

        # Check response code
        response = self.client.get('/admin/')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

        # Check 'Log in' in response
        self.assertTrue('Log in' in response.content)

    def test_create_post(self):
        # Log in
        self.client.login(username='test', password="password")

        # Check response code
        response = self.client.get('/admin/blogengine/post/add/')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

        # Create the new post
        response = self.client.post('/admin/blogengine/post/add/', {
            'title': 'My first post',
            'text': 'This is my first post',
            'pub_date_0': '2013-12-28',
            'pub_date_1': '22:00:04'
        },
        follow=True
        )
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

        # Check added successfully
        self.assertTrue('added successfully' in response.content)

        # Check new post now in database
        all_posts = Post.objects.all()
        self.assertEquals(len(all_posts), 1)

    def test_edit_post(self):
        # Create the post
        post = Post()
        post.title = 'My first post'
        post.text = 'This is my first blog post'
        post.pub_date = timezone.now()
        post.save()

        # Log in
        self.client.login(username='test', password="password")

        # Edit the post
        response = self.client.post('/admin/blogengine/post/1/', {
            'title': 'My second post',
            'text': 'This is my second blog post',
            'pub_date_0': '2013-12-28',
            'pub_date_1': '22:00:04'
        },
        follow=True
        )
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

        # Check changed successfully
        self.assertTrue('changed successfully' in response.content)

        # Check post amended
        all_posts = Post.objects.all()
        self.assertEquals(len(all_posts), 1)
        only_post = all_posts[0]
        self.assertEquals(only_post.title, 'My second post')
        self.assertEquals(only_post.text, 'This is my second blog post')

    def test_delete_post(self):
        # Create the post
        post = Post()
        post.title = 'My first post'
        post.text = 'This is my first blog post'
        post.pub_date = timezone.now()
        post.save()

        # Check new post saved
        all_posts = Post.objects.all()
        self.assertEquals(len(all_posts), 1)

        # Log in
        self.client.login(username='test', password="password")

        # Delete the post
        response = self.client.post('/admin/blogengine/post/1/delete/', {
            'post': 'yes'
        }, follow=True)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

        # Check deleted successfully
        self.assertTrue('deleted successfully' in response.content)

        # Check post amended
        all_posts = Post.objects.all()
        self.assertEquals(len(all_posts), 0)

class PostViewTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_index(self):
        # Create the post
        post = Post()
        post.title = 'My first post'
        post.text = 'This is my first blog post'
        post.pub_date = timezone.now()
        post.save()

        # Check new post saved
        all_posts = Post.objects.all()
        self.assertEquals(len(all_posts), 1)

        # Fetch the index
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

        # Check the post title is in the response
        self.assertTrue(post.title in response.content)

        # Check the post text is in the response
        self.assertTrue(post.text in response.content)

        # Check the post date is in the response
        self.assertTrue(str(post.pub_date.year) in response.content)
        self.assertTrue(post.pub_date.strftime('%b') in response.content)
        self.assertTrue(str(post.pub_date.day) in response.content)
```

## my_site > ingledow > ingledow > urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'ingledow.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^.*$', include('blogengine.urls')),
)
```

## my_site > ingeldow > blogengine > urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.generic import ListView
from blogengine.models import Post

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', 'blogengine.views.index'),
    )
```

## my_site > ingeldow > blogengine > models.py

from django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField()
```

## my_site > ingeldow > blogengine > views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from blogengine.models import Post

# Create the post list view (david.ingledow.co.uk/blog)
def index(request):
        # get the blog posts that are published
        posts = Post.objects.all
        # now return the rendered template
        return render(request, 'blogengine/index.html', {'post': posts})
```

Here's my folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template, the list of posts is called `object_list`, while in your view you're passing it through as `post`. The two need to match up.

If you change the view to the following, I think that should resolve the issue:

```
def index(request):
        # get the blog posts that are published
        posts = Post.objects.all
        # now return the rendered template
        return render(request, 'blogengine/index.html', {'object_list': posts})
```

Also, do you have Debug set to True in your settings? That would enable a stack trace that would make this easier to debug, and if the template couldn't be found it would come up with a message confirming this.

Glad you like my tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your TEMPLATE_DIRS set in settings.py? It's not finding your template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-template-dirs-setting

Comment: This is what I have in my settings.py:

`TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`